# Very simple Spring AOP pointcut

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

The `create()` pointcut works just fine, but I can't get the `setStatus()` pointcut to work however I try... I've tried with `@Before`, `@After`, `@AfterReturning`, but nothing.

According to the debugger, both methods are called.

```java
package com.baz;

@Aspect
public class ServiceAspect {
   @Pointcut("execution(* com.foo.ServiceImpl.create(..))")
    public void create() {}

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.bar.Subscription.setStatus(..))")
    public void setStatus() {}

    // works
    @AfterReturning(pointcut="create()", returning="retVal")
    public void afterCreate(Object retVal) {
        // omitted
    }

    // doesn't work
    @Before("setStatus()")
    public void status() {
        // omitted
    }

    // doesn't work
    @Before("setStatus() && args(status)")
    public void status(int status) {
        // omitted
    }

    // doesn't work
    @After("setStatus()")
    public void status() {
        // omitted
    }

    // doesn't work
    @AfterReturning(pointcut="setStatus()")
    public void status2() {
        // omitted
    }

    // doesn't work
    @AfterReturning(pointcut="setStatus()", returning="retVal")
    public void afterSetStatus(Object retVal) {
        // omitted
    }

    // doesn't work
    @Around("setStatus()")
    public Object aroundStatus(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Object output = pjp.proceed();
        return output;
    }
}
```

The methods looks like this:

```java
public class Subscription extends FooBar implements Baz {
    public void setStatus(int status) { /* ... */ }
}

public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    public Subscription create(Session session, Subscription template) { /* ... */ }
}
```

**Edit**

I've tried using both `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />`, `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>` and `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="false"/>`.

**Edit 2**

I've tried calling `setStatus()` directly on `Subscription`, but it didn't catch that either.

```
Subscription subscription = new Subscription();
subscription.setStatus(1);
```

Comment: Is `com.bar` the correct package name for the `setStatus` pointcut?

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild yep, would get a RuntimeException otherwise during initialization

Comment: Did you try calling the `setStatus()` method directly on an object of type Subscription and see if the `@Before` advice was called?

Comment: @Vikdor just tried it, didn't work either... See edit 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Subscription subscription = new Subscription();
>
> subscription.setStatus(1);

Subscription should be a spring-managed bean for the aspects to be applied, i.e. you should obtain objects of type `Subscription` from the `ApplicationContext` as follows:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = 
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:META-INF/Spring.xml");
Subscription subscription = context.getBean(Subscription.class);
```

or get them injected using `@Resource` or `@Autowired` annotations.

Then, the call to `setStatus()` on `subscription` object will go through the AOP proxy created by Spring framework and the code in the AOP advices that match the method definition get executed.

Another way to get a spring-managed bean, while creating objects using `new` operator, is using the [`@Configurable`](http://vikdor.blogspot.com/2012/08/using-configurable-to-inject-resources.html) annotation.